# Why don't properties from a protocol get auto synthesized in a class that doesn't implement them?

Tags: objective-c

I think it's technically possible for the compiler to detect that a class doesn't implement all properties from a protocol and determine the unimplemented properties and therefore it should be able to automatically synthesize them.

Is it just a not-implemented-yet feature, or if there is a good reason not to do this what is it?

Comment: Protocols have methods, not properties, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @rdelmar "Protocols can include declarations for both instance methods and class methods, as well as properties." :)

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I guess I never use protocols that way, so I was unaware.

Answer (score 0):

Because a Protocol is basically an API conformance contract. Nothing more. 
By declaring conformance to a formal Protocol you are committing to implementing the required parts if the protocol. 
You will provide a conforming interface but the implementation is up to you.

Comment: This answer is logical, but I don't think that's a 'good reason' not to auto-synthesize. By declaring a normal property in a class you're declaring that your class conforms to a particular interface (i.e. it implements the getter, and setter if not readonly). If you don't implement them or `@synthesize` them the compiler does it for you (as part of creating the class). By declaring your class conforms to a protocol you're adding those promises to your class's contract. I can't think of any reason why the compiler needs to treat these promises differently.